# Accessing automatic variables from cpprest lambda expressions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, casablanca

Suppose I have:

```
void f()
{
    SomeClass someObject;
    pplx::create_task([&]()-> SomeClass { return someObject; });
}

void g()
{
    //Allocate automatic objects
}

int main()
{
    f();
    g();
}
```

Is this guaranteed to work? my logic says no since by the time the task runs `someObject` might be out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If the lambda (or a copy thereof) is never used after `f()` returns, everything is fine. Afterwards of course `return someObject` is evaluating a reference to an object that no longer exists, which is undefined behaviour.